# Create Visual Fox Pro DBF with activex

Tags: dll, activex, foxpro, dbf

any one knows if there is a activex dll that can create VFP DBF files?
I mean im writing app with 1C:Enterprise 8.2 language, and i need to export some datas into VFP DBF. And i can only use activex dlls in this language. Would be perfect to get free dll, but i can pay also if there is anything good.

Answer (score 1):

If you DO have access to VFP development, yes, a COM DLL would easily be able to handle it.  Even without writing a full COM DLL, if you have the runtime DLLs and the OleDB provider, you can connect to directly with .Net.

If no VFP access, nor OleDB, you could also use Sybase Advantage Local Server to create and populate .DBF style files, and is a basic drop-in dll library and does NOT need to be run as a "SERVER".  From that, you could issue all your

create table ...
insert into ...

components you may need.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be specifically an ActiveX control, rather than just a regular COM server? Writing a VFP COM server to create DBF files in a specified location would be easy, but would require the development edition of VFP.